# Encoding system sorted by the number of 1

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I thought an encoding system. `arr[(encoded code)]=(decoded code)` follows:

- `arr` is an array of binary non-negative integers, less than 2^16 (pow(2, 16)).
- `arr[0]=0`
- each of `arr[1...16]` has one 1. (1, 10, 100, 1000...)
- each of `arr[17...136]` has two 1s. (11, 101, 110, 1001...)
- each of `arr[137...696]` has three 1s. (111, 1011, 1101, 1110...)
- ... each of binary in `arr[(sum of 16C(n-1))...(sum of (16Cn))-1]` has `n` 1s.
- each of `arr[65519...65534]` has fifteen 1s.
- `arr[65535]` is 2^16-1 (`1111 1111 1111 1111`).

I didn't decide how to sort in each section, and it doesn't matter. (Sections should be sorted by the number of 1, however.) Suitable encoding-decoding algorithm will decide how to sort. (e.g. It can be `arr[1]=4`, `arr[2]=2` and `arr[3]=8` if the algorithm is fine.)

I want to make an encoding function and decoding function without searching in this table. Any good solution & sorting method?

Comment: Does converting it to a binary tree count as "searching in a table"?

Comment: @Jongware Yeah, but it's okay if your thought is effectively smaller than making this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's let `C(i, j)` be the count of binary strings of length `i` with exactly `j` `1`s.  This is the well-known choose function, which is calculated as `i! / (j! * (i-j)!)`.

Let's sort them as follows.  First the `C(16, 0)` with no `1`s.  Then the `C(16, 1)` with one `1`.  Then the `C(16, 2)` with two `1`s and so on.  Within a group we sort lexicographically.  Therefore in the `C(16, 2)` group, we put the `C(15, 2)` with two trailing `1`s and a leading `0`, followed by the `C(15, 1)` with a leading `1` and a trailing `1` somewhere.

Now given a binary string, which ones came before it?  All of the ones with fewer `1`s which is `C(16, 0) + C(16, 1) + ... + C(16, i-1)` if this one has `i` ones.  And then for each `1` in the string, we know how many match it up to that spot, have a `0` there, and the rest of the `1`s later.  Which is a group of those previous.  And those are all the previous ones so add those up and we know the position that this one goes in.  This calculation takes at most 16 steps for the count with fewer `1`s and another at most `16` steps for the `1`s in the binary number for at most 32 steps.

What about the other way?  We first keep on subtracting of `f(16, 0)`, `f(16, 1)`, and so on until we find out how many `1`s must be in the binary number.  Then we start at the left and keep figuring out for each digit if we need enough before this one that we can put in a `1` and subtract off a group we found, or whether there should be a `0` here.  Again this needs at most 32 steps.