# algorithm: How to generate numbers sorted by the number of 1 in its binary representation?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I am finding an operator to generate all numbers below 2^n in the order of the number of `1` in its binary representation.
For example:

```
int next(int cur, int max) { /* ??? */ }

for (int i=0; i< 1<<6; i = next(i, 1<<6)) printf("%d ", i);
```

should give out something like:

```
0  1  2  4  8  16  32  3  5  6  9  10  12  17  18  20  24  33  34  36  40  48  7  11  13  14  19  21  22  25  26  28  35  37  38  41  42  44  49  50  52  56  15  23  27  29  30  39  43  45  46  51  53  54  57  58  60  31  47  55  59  61  62  63
```

(the order of numbers with the same number of `1` doesn't matter)

Is it possible to write a pure `next()` function without remembering any state?

---

This may looks like a duplicate of [Encoding system sorted by the number of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629807/encoding-system-sorted-by-the-number-of-1), but this question is asking about how to generate the next number instead of returning by index

Comment: Is this a "write the code for me" question?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Any description of algorithm or mathematical analysis would also be appreciated. Writing code is not the key point here.

Comment: (1) Write a function that, given an `int`, returns the number of 1 bits. (2) Fill an array with the integers 1 to N. (3) Call `qsort`, passing it a pointer to (4) A comparison function that uses your bit-counting function from (1).  Finally, (5) print out the sorted array.  If you need help counting bits or calling `qsort`, you could ask, but they're both super-common questions, so please search first.

Comment: @SteveSummit This is a feasible solution which uses extra space. I was wondering if there is any bit magic that can achieve this.

Comment: Can you define how the `n+1`th number is related to `n`th one?

Comment: Alternatively, I suppose you could (1) write a function to generate all unique permutations of a bit string, (2a) generate all permutations of `00001`, (2b) generate all permutations of `00011`, (2c) generate all permutations of `00111`, etc.

Comment: `next` needs to be a pure function? It is probably easier to remember some more state between the calls or to recursively enumerate the numbers.

Comment: @EugeneSh. There is no restriction on the specific order of generated numbers, only provided that number with fewer `1` appears before those with more `1`.

Comment: There is no problem to generate an ordered sequence containing the *same* number of `1`s. The problem is to transition to the next sequence. I guess once you do the first, you can tell which number is the last in that sequence and write the logic to detect it.

Comment: Pretend the number is an array of 0s and 1s. Locate the rightmost 01 combination. Swap these two elements, and move all the 1s to the right of it to the far right end. If no 01 combination exists, but there's still a 0, replace it with 1 and move all 1s to the far right.

Comment: example for three 1s out of 6: 00**01**11 001**01**1 0011**01** 0**01**110 010**01**1 0101**01** 01**01**10 0110**01** 011**01**0 **01**1100 100**01**1 1001**01** 10**01**10 1010**01** 101**01**0 1**01**100 1100**01** 110**01**0 11**01**00 111000; there's no more combinations of three 1s, so continue with 001111.

Comment: Note that when you have the perms of 2 bits set out of 6, you also have the perms of 4 bits set out of 6 (by inverting), similarly 1 of 6 with 5 of 6 etc.

Comment: https://ideone.com/zsaR9N a simple program that generates the same sequence recursively

Comment: @n.m. Thanks! I have also composed a C++ implementation based on your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-higher-number-with-same-number-of-set-bits/) and [n-m's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m).

The basic idea is to consider the number as a permutation of `0` and `1`s. If `cur` is not the largest number with the same number of `1`s, we can simply use next permutation algorithm to get the next one (with the implementation of bit tricks), otherwise we can return `(1 << (number_of_1(cur) + 1)) - 1`.

Here is an simple implementation. I guess it is possible to completely eliminate conditional jumps and iterations with some bit magic:

```
// https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation
static int next_perm(unsigned int v)
{
    unsigned int t = v | (v - 1); // t gets v's least significant 0 bits set to 1
    // Next set to 1 the most significant bit to change, 
    // set to 0 the least significant ones, and add the necessary 1 bits.
    return (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (__builtin_ctz(v) + 1));  
}

static int next(unsigned int cur, unsigned int max) {
    if (cur + 1 == max) return max;
    if (((cur - 1) | cur) >= max - 1) return (1 << (__builtin_popcount(cur) + 1)) - 1;
    return next_perm(cur);
}

int main() {
    for (volatile int i=0; i< 1<< 30; i = next(i, 1<<30));
}
```

[The link given by @rici](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14717440/1566221) provides another solution:

```
// end with zero
template<typename UnsignedInteger>
UnsignedInteger next_combination(UnsignedInteger comb, UnsignedInteger mask) {
  UnsignedInteger last_one = comb & -comb;
  UnsignedInteger last_zero = (comb + last_one) &~ comb & mask;
  if (last_zero) return comb + last_one + (last_zero / (last_one * 2)) - 1;
  else if (last_one > 1) return mask / (last_one / 2);
  else return ~comb & 1;
}

int main() {
    for (volatile int i = 1; i; i = next_combination(i, (1 << 30) -1));
}
```

According to my micro-benchmark with gcc-8.1.1 `-O3 -flto`:

```
➜  bitmagic git:(master) ✗ time ./next-1
./next-1  4.27s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 4.313 total
➜  bitmagic git:(master) ✗ time ./next-2
./next-2  12.42s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 12.436 total
```

Comment: @rici Thanks! I added that solution and attached my micro-benchmark result.

Comment: yeah, the división makes it really slow. You can speed it up by using CTZ and a shift. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set